# SharePoint 2010 - API/arhitecture/component details

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, documentation

I'm about to embark on SharePoint 2010 development and need some details about it from a developer point of view.

I've watched countless videos that describe how to create sites, views, manage documents etc but couldn't find any useful development resources (or maybe I wasn't looking in the right place... I don't know).

So, my question is, where can I find API information, component details, how SharePoint 2010 is build underneath and how can I work with that. I need some online resources to quicly get me up to speed and also act as reference documentation later on.

Where can I find such info?

Answer (score 2):

There is a **[StackExchange site dedicated to SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)** - these two questions may be a good starting point for you:

- [What are the best resources for SharePoint 2010 development?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/1910/950)
- [What resources would you recommend to someone who would like to learn and possibly become a SharePoint Developer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/8/950)

Many SharePoint specialists use Twitter - [these are the ones I followed](https://twitter.com/#!/chopeen/sharepoint/members) in my SharePoint days.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best resources on SharePoint Development is the MSDN SharePoint Portal

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default

Or the MSDN SharePoint Developer Modules on

http://www.mssharepointdeveloper.com

you should also have a look on

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint 2010 SDK

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253.aspx

Answers quite a bit of the questions that you have here.  It may not be the greatest resource in the world for hard, complicated examples, but it does have lots of intro topics that will get you started with different aspects of the product.