# Sharepoint 2010 Beginner - best site to learn the basic

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to learn sharepoint. Can anyone tell me what are the best site to learn sharepoint at the beginner level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharePoint 2010 - API/arhitecture/component details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118118/sharepoint-2010-api-arhitecture-component-details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn development, Get these hands on lab from Microsoft site:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17215

If you want to learn sharepoint as an end user,  you can download this end user training guide

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/Pages/End-User-Training-Guide.aspx

Comment: is there any good textual tutorial for share point? [textual because videos are not allowed where i work, otherwise i would have played lynda tutorials]

Answer (score 1):

Nice way to start with Sharepoint 10 basics by Videos. Please follow the following link for that.
http://webtech-training.blogspot.in/2013/11/learn-sharepont-2010-basics.html

Comment: Link only answers should be posted as comments

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for training courses then check this following link from Microsoft officials

https://mva.microsoft.com/product-training/sharepoint

Orif you want to learn sharepoint step by step using tutorial videos, articles and other learning resources check this link below

http://www.learnsharepointtrainingtutorial.net.in

Hope this will help you

Comment: Link only answers should be posted as comments

Comment: @NSNoob, please guide me, to improve my comments..Thanks